# In Nextflow, Does a process with a channel.fromPath is parallelized?

Tags: nextflow

I have a process in Nextflow with multiple input file from a Channel.FromPath().

Here my script:

```
params.queries = ""
queries = Channel.fromPath(params.queries) #path to multiple .fasta files

process PsiBlast {

input:
file query from queries_psiblast

output:
file top_hits

"""
blastpgp -d $db -i $query -j 2 -C ff.chd.ckp -Q pssm.out >> top_hits
"""
}

#then there are others processes, not needed for my question.
```

What I want to know is if my process is parallelized? If it run on 2 files at the same time for example? Or do I need to specify it in my script?

I read the doc, but it's not specify. And I don't know how to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Nextflow processes are implicitly parallelised provided there's are enough cpus/mem to fulfil the parallel execution.